# WordPress: Add aligncenter to Gutenberg groups block

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

Per default, the Gutenberg groups block has only two alignment options: `wide` and `full width`.

I now want to add a custom alignment `center` to the block. Other blocks like images have this option.

Is there any way to extend a core block like this?

I know that there is an option for custom styles with `registerBlockStyle` ([See docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/javascript/extending-the-block-editor/)).

But is there also something like this for basic controls/settings? I couldn't find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer [here](https://wptips.dev/change-gutenberg-alignment/).

It works, if I change the code like this:

```
wp.hooks.addFilter( 'blocks.registerBlockType',
  'my/change_alignment', ( settings, name ) => {

  switch( name ) {
    case 'core/group':
    case 'core/cover':
      return lodash.assign( {}, settings, {
        supports: lodash.assign( {}, settings.supports, {
          align: [ 'center', 'wide', 'full']
        } ),
      } );
  }

  return settings;
});
```